# ASP.Net re-deployment - bin folder only

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment

I have a website in visual studio 2010.  When I publish the site (not updatable, no fixed naming, etc. - just a simple publish) it creates the entire site for me, with every aspx and ashx etc as markers only.  The bin folder is where everything is actually located.

If I make a change to the website code (only in the code file(s)) - when I publish the site again, I could redeploy only the bin folder, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can just deploy the dlls in the bin if the changes are only in the code behind

Comment: Thanks.  I wanted to check that I was sane.  It seems to have worked just fine (the QA site I just published).